# Can Linux run ASPX coded websites?

Tags: webserver, asp.net, linux

My website is a set of ASP.NET/ASPX files with C# code embedded in <script runat=server> blocks with some DLLs - all .NET managed code, nothing weird. I wrote it so I'm able to make small changes.

It currently runs on a Windows Server with IIS. Could I take that website code and run it on a Linux server?
If so, what would I need to install for it to work? (Mono? Microsoft's .NET for Linux?)

What "gotchas" should I be aware of if I go down this route?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116175/running-asp-net-on-a-linux-based-server

Comment: This question is really best suited for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), though it appears to already be answered over at Stack Overflow as pointed out in the comment above.